# Inject some code in the middle of the Python function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any way to inject some code in the middle of the Python function before specific operation?

E.g. this is my function:

```
def my_function(myList):
   myList.append(3)
   myList.remove(4)
   myList.append(5)
```

and I need to inject (e.g. using decorator) additional operation before `remove` operation. Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: No in a standard way.  If possible, it would require very weird meta programming.

Comment: you would want to look into `exec` or `eval`

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the operations in a `list` and then calling all of them in your function:

```
operations = [
    lambda x: x.append(3),
    lambda x: x.remove(3),
    lambda x: x.append(5),
]

def my_function(myList):
    for operation in operations:
        operation(myList)
```

Now if you want to inject an additional operation into your function, just add it to `operations`:

```
new_operation = lambda x: x.append(4)
operations.insert(1, new_operation)
```

Comment: I have to inject transformation to an existing function and unfortunately I cannot modify its body. But thanks for your suggestion!